# Sometimes Notifications cause iOS screen to just wake up

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, iphone-x

That's really weird problem..my notifications is working perfectly but in very random and rare cases, the screen just is woken up but no notification appears.
Although I'm using native Swift, it seems it's a common problem 
[IOS Push notification - Sometimes only wakes screen and plays sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092087/ios-push-notification-sometimes-only-wakes-screen-and-plays-sound)

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a line of code that reduces the application badge number when a notification is received, make sure that this line doesn't get called when app state is not "Active".

Comment: Using breakpoint this line is not called when notification is received but I will add this condition anyway, thanks.